# Calculate Factor thats 1 if value is not 0, and 0 if it is

Tags: calculus, algorithms

I don't know if this is the right stackexchange for this question, please tell me/move it if it isn't.

I calculate a value $x$ that can be any integer number. I now want to use this variable to get a factor thats $0$ if $x$ is zero, and 1 if it isn't.

I can easily program this with an if-statement, however due to optimization reasons, I  want to get around the if. So I was wondering if there is a mathematical expression that would give me $fac = 1$ if $x\ne0$ and $fac=0$ if $x = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a new variable equal to the floor of $x/(x-1)$. ( as long as $x$ can't be equal to $1$). Alternatively the ceiling of $x/(x+1)$ (as long as $x$ isn't negative).

Comment: In theory good, but if $x=1$, I have an integer division by zero, which is not good. using $x$ as a floating point number and calculating the floor, gives me for $x=1$ $fac=-2147483684.000$ (I think that's not a math problem but a programming problem).

Comment: @Fl.pf. My bad, you could do  the ceiling of $x/(x+1)$ as long as $x$ can't be negative.

Comment: I'm having the same problems with the ceiling function as with the floor function. Pretty weird that floor and ceiling give me the same result. That shouldn't happen, right?

Comment: @Fl.pf. That is rather bizarre. $\lceil\frac{x}{x+1}\rceil\equiv 1\ \forall\ x\in\mathbb{Z}^+$

Comment: it is. But I think this is now purely programming weirdness and your solution is still right, so I'll figure that out somehow. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Thanks, apologies I couldn't be of more help.